# apache camel file2 removes file while java stream is reading the file

Tags: java, java-8, apache-camel, java-stream

I have a camel file2 dropbox listener to detect a file and then read other files in the same directory. Apache Camel will add a `.camelLock` marker when the file is detected and removes it withing few seconds. 
Now the problem is, in very occasional cases my code detects the `.camelLock` file (as it is not deleted by camel yet) and before it finishes the following method, camel removes the file. So my method returns `java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Here is the documentation to camel file2: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

```
private List<String> getFileNames(String fullPath) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.walk(Paths.get(fullPath))) {

            return pathStream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .filter(f -> !f.toString().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith("camellock"))
                    .map(Path::toString)
                    .map(f -> f.substring(f.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1, f.length()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the exceptions.

Comment: You must have some Camel route that starts with from file. Can you tell more about that. Also read more about Camel's file component and the readLock option to understand that better.

Comment: @tsolakp all you need from the stack trace is the one that I provided and also I explained in detail about the problem.

Comment: @ClausIbsen yes I linked to the camel documentation therefore I read it already. The problem is not with camel configuration or routing, it is just about the way I stream to make sure it does not throw exception. I can fix it by using different implementation but I really like the way I implemented to read the files.